# How to properly reset iCloud storage for an App

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I am now adding iCloud to my app and to be able to test the upgrade scenario I need to totally reset the iCloud storage every now and then.

Is deleting the app and the app data from the Settings enough? I did that before and it caused lots of errors.

What is the proper way to totally reset iCloud settings and storage for an app to start as if it is a totally new app installation?

Cheers and Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Deleting the app is not enough -- indeed the very benefit of iCloud is that it is outside the app sandbox. The process may vary depending on what type of iCloud solution you're using.

If you're using CoreData, it's going to be a matter of programmatically traversing your model stack and deleting (if you have a well designed model with the proper delete rules, hopefully you can delete from your highest-level relation and let the deletions flow down).

If you're using a key value store, it's pretty simple:

Get a reference to your iCloud ubiquity store, something like this (presumably you've already got one somewhere):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *ubiquitousStore;
```

To clear it, enumerate the objects it contains and delete them:

```
- (void)cleariCloudUbiquitousStore
{
    // Clear everything regardless of actual key:
    for (NSString *key in self.ubiquitousStore.dictionaryRepresentation.allKeys)
    {
            [self.ubiquitousStore removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    // Sync back to iCloud    
    [self.ubiquitousStore synchronize];

}
```